# Extract json from file which contains two or more json objects

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

There is a file which contains two or more json string like this:

```
{
"a":"1",
"b":"2"
}
{
"c":"3",
"d":"4"
}
```

how to use python to transform these json string to json Object from this file?

Comment: I would fix how that file is created to make valid JSON

Comment: Those are not valid JSON objects because there's no comma between the values.

Comment: @cricket_007  sorry, I forget it! I fix it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to split every occurrence of `}\W*{` while preserving the brackets and then convert every item in the result with [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json
import re

s = '''{
"a":"1",
"b":"2"
}
{
"c":"3",
"d":"4"
}'''

res = [json.loads(g) for g in re.split(r'(?<=})\W*(?={)', s)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'b': '2', 'a': '1'}, {'c': '3', 'd': '4'}]
```

In the regular expression above `(?<=})` is positive lookbehind assertion which causes `\W*` to match only if it is immediately preceded by `}`. Similarly `(?={)` is positive lookahead assertion that requires `{` to follow `\W*`.

**Update** Alternatively you can use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) to find matches instead of splitting the string. It will also work in a case where there's no whitespace between the objects:

```
import json
import re

s = '''{
"a":"1",
"b":"2"
}{
"c":"3",
"d":"4"
}
{
"foo":"bar"
}'''

res = [json.loads(m.group(0)) for m in re.finditer(r'({.*?}\W*(?=({|$)))', s, re.DOTALL)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, {'d': '4', 'c': '3'}, {'foo': 'bar'}]
```

Note that both of the methods above will break if your JSON has a string with `} {` with any amount of whitespace in between.

Comment: Thanks! I got it!

Comment: how to match `}{` using regular expression? I use `re.split(r'(?<=})(?={)', s)`, but always failed.

Comment: @Guo `}{` **is** that expression.

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry! I didn't express clearly. I mean, I need split `}{` to `}` and `{`, but `re.split(r'(?<=})(?={)', s)` can't split it.

Comment: @Guo Updated the answer to work with separate JSON objects on the same line.

Comment: @niemmi Thanks a lot!